# jacocoTestReport SKIPPED in Intellij : Skipping task ':jacocoTestReport' as task onlyIf is false

Tags: jacoco, intellij-13

In Intellij, I have integrated jacoco, so that I can generate the jacoco Reort and put that on SonarQube to check code coverage. However, when I execute using command ./gradlew jacocoTestReport ,BUILD is SUCCESSFULLt but Task: jacocoTestReport SKIPPED. No .xm/.html report is generated. I tried various combination given on Google.
I am using Junit5 and Spring Boot 2.6.2.

I checked the other threads but none of the solution worked for me.

Here is the gradle task script:

```
    test {
        useTestNG()
        useJUnitPlatform()
        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

        reports {
            junitXml.required = true
            html.required = false
        }
    }

    jacocoTestReport {

        dependsOn test

        reports {
            xml.enabled true
            csv.enabled false
            xml.destination file("${buildDir}/build/jacoco.xml")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. If I run it with `-i` for additional logging I see message: `> Task :clx-pizza-e2e-test:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
Skipping task ':clx-pizza-e2e-test:jacocoTestReport' as task onlyIf is false.
:clx-pizza-e2e-test:jacocoTestReport (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.`
Its still saying that `onlyIf` is false even if I set it explicitly to true with `jacocoTestReport.onlyIf {true}`